# Xamarin namespace issues in XAML files when changing startup project in VS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have issues with Xamarin in Visual studio 2017 15.8.0 Preview 4 (And all previous builds)

I have a Xamarin forms project with a Android Project and a UWP project, if I change the startup project to UWP and try to compile I get this error

> Error     Failed to resolve assembly: 'FoosballXamarin.Android,
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'  FoosballXamarin.UWP ...\Views\LoginPage.xaml

And the XAML itself will give me errors on these lines

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:FoosballXamarin.ViewModels;assembly=FoosballXamarin.Android"
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:FoosballXamarin.Helpers;assembly=FoosballXamarin.Android"
```

And want me to change them to

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:FoosballXamarin.ViewModels;assembly=FoosballXamarin.UWP"
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:FoosballXamarin.Helpers;assembly=FoosballXamarin.UWP"
```

Is there a way to write it differently so I dont get this error every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the errors you're seeing, I'm going to guess you have this configured as a shared project (not PCL/.netstandard). If that's the case, simplify the lines in the XAML file to:

```
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:FoosballXamarin.ViewModels"
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:FoosballXamarin.Helpers"
```

In other words, just remove the assembly= part.  If you don't specify the assembly on the xmlns line, it will assume the namespace is the same assembly as the XAML file.  So you only need to include it if it's in a different assembly.

Since shared projects include the XAML file in multiple assemblies (one per platform), you pretty much have to omit the assembly= on the xmlns declaration for namespaces/types in the same assembly.

Comment: Created a new project with .NET standard and migrated my files, seems to run better now, only one nuget package which ain't compatible with the new

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved it in a differently. I just had to add that specific project that fails to resolve in my assembly.